# how to copy particular content lines alone in notepad ++

Tags: notepad++, selection, multipleselection

I am having a huge dump file with me(more than 100000 lines of data) i want to select around 1000 lines of data from this dump.

Example:

10 ABRAHAM 90 RV EDU0MST

11 ABRAHAM 90 RV EDU0MST

19 ABRAHAM 90 RV EDU0MST

10 ABRAHAM 90 RV EDU0MST

12 ABRAHAM 90 RV EDU0MST

10 ABRAHAM 90 RV EDU0MST

from above sample data , i need to copy all the lines which are all starting with value 10. Kindly help out me please.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a program.

Comment: any dedicated options with any tools for this ?

Comment: This may help: https://superuser.com/questions/290247/how-to-delete-all-lines-in-notepad-except-lines-containing-a-word-i-need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done easily using the Find tool. I use > to indicate left click.

```
Find > Mark
    Find what: ^10
    Bookmark line = yes
    Search mode = Regular expression
     > Mark All
Search > Bookmark > Copy Bookmarked lines
New
Edit > Paste
```

Good Luck with your task,
Chris G.